# How to use Intel Compiler in Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, intel

I installed Intel Parallel Studio on Ubuntu 18.04, but when I try to use `ICC` (/opt/intel/bin/cc), I receive the error:

```
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2015.3.187/compiler/include/math.h(1214): 
error: identifier "_LIB_VERSION_TYPE" is undefined
```

According to the [Intel forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/777466), the error is because Ubuntu 18.04 is an unsupported OS. However, the latest supported version is 14.04. The same for other Linux distributions, at least 4 years old.

Many programmers should use Intel compiler on latest versions of Linux distributions (including Ubuntu), and therefore, this error should have a solution. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case the solution really has to come from Intel, and they do appear to be working on it; quoting the reply given to the forum post you linked:

> Currently our latest version doesn't support Ubuntu 18.4LTS. We will let you know when it's available.

[2018 release 2](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-parallel-studio-xe-release-notes-and-new-features#2018u2) supports Ubuntu 17.10, and [2019 beta](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-parallel-studio-xe-release-notes-and-new-features#2019beta) supports 18.04 so you’ll get support when that’s released (the beta is already available for download).

Comment: 16.04 is still unsupported. This means that it will take at least another 2 years to support 18.04. It seems that have no interest in supporting Linux distributions.

Comment: You're right. My Intel Parallel Studio is not the latest version. I have to wait for 2019 beta.

Comment: Oh, it is already available. I shouldn't wait until 2019 :)